# Empty space in UILabel - attributed text set from HTML

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell with a label inside, auto-layout is set correctly. I am trying to set the attributed text like this:

```
 dataString = [dataString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<style>body{font-family: 'RobotoCondensed-Regular'; font-size:11px;}</style>"]];
NSMutableAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding] } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
_scheduleLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
```

dataString is `<p>L-D: <b>10-22</b></p>`
The tableview has UITableViewAutomaticDimension, and the problem is that the label has extra white space after the text and it messes up the whole layout. Why does this happen and how can I remove it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me. My solution is to replace

tag in html with  and  and it removes the white spaces.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about your solution? It seems I am also seeing the same issue at my end.

Comment: Replace <p>L-D: <b>10-22</b></p> with L-D: <b>10-22</b>